# How to allow only numbers in (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I want to add a integrity constraint which only lets numeric data be added to the **Unit_Price**.

```
Create Table Invoice
(InvoiceID Varchar2(6) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Quantity number(10) NOT NULL, 
Date_of_purchase Date NOT NULL,
Unit_Price number(5,2) CHECK (ISNUMERIC(Unit_Price)) NOT NULL, 
Amount number(10) NOT NULL,
payment_method Varchar(18) CHECK (payment_method in ('Cash','Card','Paypal')) NOT NULL);
```

Also, I have a email column in another table, how can I make it so a @ sign is required. Furthermore, if they dont enter email then it should be ' ‘unknow@gmail.con’ as default?

Edit: Sorry the datatype was supposed to be varchar2 and not number, thus the need for the constraint.

Comment: Please provide an example where you've successfully stored non-numeric data in your UNIT_PRICE field. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `unit_price` IS a number.  There is no need to check that is is a number; the data type takes care of that.

The basic definition for email would be:

```
email varchar2(255) default 'unknown@gmail.com' check (email like '%@%.%')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=705e983fec682ba7abe7a5c121d93abc) is a db<>fiddle.

I strongly advise you to not use a default like that, though.  `NULL` makes much more sense in this situation.

Comment: oh ok, thanks for letting me know. For my assignment it says I have to have a default for the email if it is left blank. I tried this, the @ sign code works but when it is left blank it dosent set the deafult to the one specified.

Comment: @Ahmed . . . The code works.  I added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Yeah working now, I made a mistake, thanks once again.